# Issues using setSupportActionBar() + android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar

I have experiencing some issues using the android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar and have been pulling my hair out for several days trying to get this working.

Specifically, I cannot modify the title or load menu items into the app/action bar.

Any help that you can provide would be most appreciated!  Otherwise, I am going to chunk all of this and try to build a custom application toolbar with dedicated text icons.  If this is the right approach, let me know!  Thanks!

I believe that I building the toolbar correctly, but when I attempt to update the title, nothing happens.  Furthermore, no menus are loaded via onOptionsItemSelected().  In fact, onOptionsItemSelected is not even called.

1. compileSdkVersion 25
2. buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
3. minSdkVersion 21
4. targetSdkVersion 25

Interestingly enough, if I place the same setSupportActionBar() related code into the onOptionsItemSelected() method, it works.  Of course, that assumes that you have menu key to hit, since I have not seen how to call onOptionsItemSelected() on some handsets without a menu key.

I have tested it using both the emulated Nexus 6 API 25 built-into Android Studio and a Samsung Galaxy S6 API 22 via Genymotion.

Same results.

**toolbar_main.xml**

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
  android:titleTextColor="@color/White"
  android:elevation="4dp"
  android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
  app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"
  app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
  app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
              android:background="@color/Black"
              android:orientation="vertical">

   <include
         android:id="@+id/main_custom_toolbar"
         layout="@layout/toolbar_main"/>

   <TextView
         android:id="@+id/test_header"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@color/Black"
         android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="HoneyDo Tasks"
         android:textColor="@color/Yellow"
         android:textSize="30dp"
         android:textStyle="bold">
   </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_custom_toolbar);
      setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
      getSupportActionBar().setTitle("New Title");
   }


   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
   {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
      return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }
```

Comment: Are you using CollapsingToolbarLayout ..?

Comment: You need to return `true` in the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` override, from the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)   `You must return true for the menu to be displayed; if you return false it will not be shown.`

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you minimal code that works for me:

xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

You can skip `AppBarLayout` and only use `ToolBar`

Also make changes in your `AndroidManifest`:

```
<activity
        android:name="YourActivityName"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
```

and in your `styles.xml`:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```